# How to concatenate three fields as one and display in a datagridview table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my `DataGridView`, I have field as `Borrower name` and I'm using a form to collect the `First Name`, `Middle Name` and `Last Name`. So what I want is to set `First Name`, `Middle Name` and `Last Name` values as `Borrower name` in my `DataGridView`.

I did something like this, Which only shows `First Name` at the moment.

```
datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["first_name"].ToString();
```

I tried changing item name to `"first_name+, middle_name+, last_name"` but the program breaks.

How can I achieve this? So that I can concatenate `First Name`, `Middle Name` and `Last Name` values as `Borrower name`.

Here's my full code:

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from user_reg where user_type = 'Member' ",conn);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    datagrid_borrowers.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        int n = datagrid_borrowers.Rows.Add();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = (n + 1).ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["user_id"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["first_name"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["address"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["sex"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["nic_number"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["contact_number"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["email_address"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: add one more field in sql query (with correct synatx for string concatenation, of course), eg: `Select *, first_name+middle_name+last_name  from ...`. and also: you can use `DataSource` property (`datagrid_borrowers.DataSource = dt;`) instead of adding rows in a loop

Comment: This is the dirtiest way of working with `DataGridView`. Why you don't use data binding? Then you can use more elegant solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["first_name"].ToString() 
                                    + " " + item["middle_name"].ToString()
                                    + " " + item["last_name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from user_reg where user_type = 'Member' ",conn);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    datagrid_borrowers.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        int n = datagrid_borrowers.Rows.Add();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = (n + 1).ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["user_id"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["first_name"].ToString() + item["middle_name"].ToString() + item["last_name"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["address"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["sex"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["nic_number"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["contact_number"].ToString();
        datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["email_address"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used data table adapter to fetch data from your database so result will be a collection of [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) objects

for accessing fields that stored in each object you should use Indexer, as you can see in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx)  you have to pass just one column name to this indexer.

the simplest way is to use String.Format, as this

```
datagrid_borrowers.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
    item["first_name"].ToString()
    item["Middle_name"].ToString()
    item["Last_name"].ToString()
);
```

this way your code will be clean and more readable.

Comment: I didn't know about this, will try to use this. Really like the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the full power of data binding!

Also use [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from user_reg where user_type = 'Member' ",conn);
dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

// Add full_name column with expression.
dt.Columns.Add("Full Name", typeof(string),
    "first_name + ' ' + middle_name + ' ' + last_name");

datagrid_borrowers.DataSource = dt; // data binding

// Hide unnecessary columns.
datagrid_borrowers.Columns["first_name"].Visible = false;
datagrid_borrowers.Columns["middle_name"].Visible = false;
datagrid_borrowers.Columns["last_name"].Visible = false;
```

Note that you should not be manually created columns in `DataGridView`.

Comment: I will check this @Alexander but why shouldn't I create columns manually?

Comment: @DilumJayawardhana - Because the columns are created automatically.